# black screen on fresh install of 12.04

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

When I try to install 12.04, I get a black screen.  I also get the black screen when i try the Livecd.  I did get it to work by using the "nomodeset" setting in grub, but know the resolution on my lcd is wrong.

Comment: Wouldn't happen to be Server edition would it? There is a bug in the installer which causes it to hang. Refer to Bug [#995144](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/995144) and [#998292](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/998292)